# 400 Bad Request using Axios get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, axios

I'm read request method aliases

```
axios.get(url[, config])
```

and i try to do method

```js
const axios = require('axios')
let data = new Date()
let timer = date.getTime()
const config = {
  'kc-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', // primary key
  'kc-api-sign': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // screat key
  'kc-api-timestamp' : timer,      // timestamp
  'kc-api-passpharase : 'xxxxxxx ' // passpharase

axios.get('https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts/',config)
  .then(r => {
    console.log('Ok')
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log('Error')
  })
```

> return 400 Bad Request -- Invalid request format  now I don't know how to fix it.
>
> Message : 'Request failed with status code 400'

Comment: Not enough data. How a properly formed request should look like, and how does your request (see browser, dev tools, Network tab) actually look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the way to define headers:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'kc-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', // primary key
        'kc-api-sign': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // screat key
        'kc-api-timestamp' : timer,      // timestamp
        'kc-api-passpharase : 'xxxxxxx ' // passpharase
    }
}

axios.get('https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts', config)
```

Comment: I do as you say

Message : Request failed with status code 401  ( Unauthorized -- Invalid API Key. )

Comment: And is the API key valid? Again: look at the request going out, and compare it with what _should_ be going out.

Comment: I know what the cause is KC-API-SIGN

Message  : 'Invalid KC-API-SIGN'

i must to convert key-secret to key-sign

Answer (score -1):

In your config variable, make sure you wrap your keys in double quotes.

Properties in JSON have to be strings wrapped in double quotes. In other words using single quotes, or no quotes at all is not allowed.

Comment: JSON indeed requires double quotes round the keys, but this is a JavaScript Object, not JSON. JS Objects work fine with single quotes or even no quotes at all. And when the JS Object is serialized into JSON, it will add the double quotes for you.

Comment: Also you mention that properties have to be strings. That is only true for the keys. The values can also be numbers, booleans, arrays, objects and nulls.